# How to center UITextField text in Swift

Tags: ios, uitextfield, swift

I have a UITextField object with the text property set to "hi". However these two lines have no affect on where "hi" is located

```
 myUITextObject.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Center
 myUITextObject.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Center
```

Is this a bug in Swift? If so how do I go about logging this as a bug so Apple can fix it in the next Swift release?

Comment: @dasdom yes, and that did not work

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You would want to write it like this:

```
myUITextObject.textAlignment = .center
```

(Edited to change from .Center to .center)

Comment: Note also that myUITextObject.contentVerticalAlignment can be set to .Top, .Center, .Fill or .Bottom to affect the vertical alignment

Comment: This only centers the text horizontally and `myUITextObject.contentVerticalAlignment` is not a thing anymore. Any ideas how to achieve vertical centering without doing a weird offset hack.

Comment: Changed to myUITextObject.alignment = .center

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the textAlignment property; try this:

`myUITextObject.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;`

Comment: The code shown in this answer won't work in Swift (it would in Objective-C).

Comment: @Anna you're right, and I changed the correct answer to be Dave's

Comment: @Anna just curious, why did the code I first pasted in not work, from other SO posts it appeared like that was the way to do it. And having two different ways of doing the exact same thing seems strange.

Comment: In Swift it would look like this: 
textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;

Answer (score 1):

**Another way to do it**, is by using the storyboard.

In fact there is a Vertical and Horizontal Control that you can use for align your element inside the `UITextField`.
In the case above that align the text to the *top left*:

[image]

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5 2021**

```
yourTextField.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "String for textfield", attributes: [.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle])
```