# Justify-aligning text in a text view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, justify

It's a pretty trivial question I know, but I have to be able to justify-align the text in a text view using swift. It is an already existing text view on the storyboard which has been hooked up to an outlet, let's call it `justifyTextView`.

Can anybody give some code for this? I can't seem to find anything online about it.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24589062/2521004)

Comment: Please include [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) in your post.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Justified
```

Comment: the question relates to a UITextView and not a UILabel

Comment: @Edward True, but the effect is the same in this case. The `textAlignment` setter is also available on a UITextView.